# Custom validation after submit button is pressed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

Is there a way I can make a link_to submit button run some custom validation?

I need help writing a validation that checks the presence of certain fields and ALSO make sure there are at least 4 entries in a nested form array. Im using the gem cocoon for the nested form and the project requires that the user has at least 4 questions attached to their application form.

my associations are as follows:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
end


class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
end
```

Multistep controller:

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

  steps :personal, :school, :grades, :extra_activity, :paragraph, :submit

  def show
    @user = User.find(current_user)
      case step
    when :school, :grades, :extra_activity, :paragraph, :submit
    @question = Question.find(current_user)
  end
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    case step
    when :school, :grades, :extra_activity, :paragraph, :submit
    @question =  Question.find(current_user)
    @question.update_attributes(question_params)
    end

    render_wizard @user
  end
```

The multistep question form is built once the user is created.

So for example on the second page of my wicked form, i'm trying to validate the presence of a highschool name `validates :highschool, :presence => true`  but im still able to submit the form on the last submit page without highschool filled out.

**SOLUTION:**

I created a migration on the user called "steps", which is a string.

I then add the following code into the user model:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :minimum_number_of_questions_required, if: "step == 'extra_activity'"

  private

  def minimum_number_of_questions_required
    if questions.count < 4
      errors[:base] << "You must have at least 4 questions attached."
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my user_steps controller which handles turning my multiple models into a single multi page form, I added the following in my update method:

```
case step
when :extra_activity
  @user.step = step.to_s
end
```

So in simple english, what is happening is that rails is tracking the user based on which step of the form they are on. Based on the step, we can then run the validations specific to the forms step.

This is useful for the fact that I only need a min of 4 questions on the extra_activity step, but was not letting me get past the previous steps because the validation wouldn't let it. Remember we are working with the same model.

Gems used: Cocoon (for simple nested forms) and Wicked (for simple multistep forms)

Comment: Are these validations always supposed to be enforced or only when this specific form is submitted?

Comment: @ArtinBoghosian after the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these validations should always be enforce, and by that I mean whenever you attempt to save a App it must have at least 4 questions then you would add like so:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :minimum_number_of_questions_required

  private

  def minimum_number_of_questions_required
    if questions.count < 4
      errors[:base] << "You must have at least 4 questions attached."
    end
  end
end
```

If you only wanted it to occur when that form was submitted you could set a variable in the App class that lets the object know that it should actually run the minimum question validation:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :validate_questions

  validate :minimum_number_of_questions_required, if: :validate_questions

  # same code as above for validation
end
```

You have to make sure that your code/form sets the validates_question variable to some value that will evaluate to true. I'm not a huge fan of this method but it is quick and easy. Other than that I think you would have to create some sort of Facade object or form object that sits in front of this ActiveRecord model and does the validations your form requires.

```
class AppForm
  include ActiveModel::Validation

  # move validations code here
end
```

Comment: For some reason it wont work for me. Could it be because the view is connected to the multi step controller I have set up?

Comment: Can you post your controller code as well so I can get some context on how you are actually using the form data?

Comment: @DillonRaphael is highschool name on the user model?

Comment: Question is a nested attribute to App

Comment: @DillonRaphael this might seem like a shady thing to do, but can you move that validation into the question model by changing the if statement to be if app.questions.count < 4 and adding the error on the question just to see if the validation runs or not?

Comment: ya still nothing. although it works when im not using the multistep controller

Comment: @DillonRaphael I'm wondering if you have to go thorugh the user model as the root using accepts_nested_attributes_for. I know the Wicked gem is going to call save on the user and if user is valid then it won't care about any errors. So when you do render_wizard user, the gem will call save on user and if it succeeds will consider it a success. So unless everything is going through the user you will have this issue. You might want to also want to raise questions.valid?.inspect in your controller just to see if it is valid or not.

Comment: You think there might be a way to do this with javascript? Im currently validating other form options using the DOM like so "user[firstname]":{required:true},

Comment: I got it to work by changing private to protected on the user model. Very good call. Only issue, the error isn't showing.

Comment: @DillonRaphael in your update method on your controller can you try doing something like. if question.update_attributes(question_params); then render_wizard user; else; render_wizard end. Because like i said before, it's going to call save on user whne you do render_wizard user and we know that user is already valid based on the fact that it is already in the db.

Comment: I added the solution to the original question. You helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @DillonRaphael I'm glad you were able to figure it out :-).